# Problems in displaying pandas dataframe from an SQL database to a QTableview widget that is nested in a QTabWidget in PyQT Designer

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyqt6

I am trying to display the **pandas** `dataframe` to a `QTableView` Widget that is nested in a `QTabWidget` in **PyQT** Designer. Below is my Python code

```py
con = sqlite3.connect(self.fname)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(self.fsqlquery)
        data = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
        data.columns = [x[0] for x in cur.description]

        model = QStandardItemModel()
        for row in range(data.shape[0]):
            for column in range(data.shape[1]):
                item = QStandardItem(str(data.iloc[row, column]))
                model.setItem(row, column, item)

        tableview = self.tabwid.widget(2).findChild(QTableView, 'tableview')
        tableview.setModel(model)
        tableview.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

I keep getting the error `setModel(self, model: QAbstractItemModel): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QStandardItemModel'`. Appreciate some help in resolving this error.

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre] and include the full traceback of the error. Be also, you're not mixing PyQt and PySide together (or different Qt versions), are you? How are you generating the UI that you're using in your code?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I realised that i have been mixing different version of PyQt and that helps to solve the problem. Thanks.